What does spring-instrument.jar do that aspectj-weaver.jar does not?
I'm trying to configure my Spring Boot application to use AspectJ load-time weaving. Using byte-buddy agent to hot-attatch the aspectj-weaver.jar seems to be working fine for both Spring beans and non-Spring classes (e.g. MyBatis TypeHandlers). However I also see a lot of recommendations, including the Spring doc, on attaching spring-instruments.jar and using the @EnableLoadTimeWeaving annotation.

What exactly does the spring-instruments.jar do that aspectj-weaver.jar does not? In my experience, even for Spring beans, spring-instruments.jar agent does not seem to be always sufficient to enable LTW, and aspectj-weaver.jar agent still needs to be available, otherwise (sometimes) there are errors around not being able to find the aspectOf method.
If both spring-instruments.jar (with @EnableLoadTimeWeaving) and aspectj-weaver.jar are attatched, will Spring beans be woven twice?



It does something similar to what you are doing with byte-buddy-agent, i.e. hot-attach aspectjweaver. I.e., you are basically re-inventing the wheel. The downside to hot-attaching is that it is too late to weave some classes and classloaders already active before hot-attachment takes place. The better alternative is to use javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar, because then attachment occurs as early as possible.

No, nothing will be woven twice.


Now, if you absolutely wish to avoid -javaagent:... but are using an executable (Spring Boot) JAR, I have a goodie for you. Quoting from other answers I wrote in similar contexts here:

If you are running your applications as executable JARs on JRE 9+ (Spring Boot ones or other types), probably Agent Embedder Maven Plugin is what you want.
It enables you to embed a java agent in your executable JAR and have it started automatically using the Launcher-Agent-Class JVM mechanism.
Unique features added by this plugin and unavailable via the original JVM mechanism: You can

embed and run multiple agents (the JVM supports only one out of the box),
pass an option string to each agent, just like from the JVM command line.

Spoiler: I am the author of the plugin and also happen to be the current maintainer of AspectJ.
P.S.: In the case of the AspectJ weaver, as the JVM starts the agent very early, weaving will be active without extra Spring configuration and it should work for all classloaders - no more ClassLoader [...] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method errors as seen when hot-attaching the weaver via spring-instrument.jar.

Thanks man, was hoping that you would answer this question. Really like the plugin (starred it on github) but my current project is using Gradle.

Am I understanding it correctly that spring-instruments.jar and @EnableLoadTimeWeaving is just switching on aspectj-weaver.jar hot-attatching, and replacing Spring AOP with aspectj ltw when loadTimeWeaver bean is loaded?
If I don't attatch spring-instruments.jar (and no @EnableLoadTimeWeaving), does that mean Spring AOP proxies are still enabled while aspectj-weaver.jar also performs ltw, potentially applying an aspect twice?


Also want to add some interesting observations  - if I attatch aspectj-weaver.jar and apply an aspect on a Spring bean, I see that the aspect executed twice when the method is called. One on the original method, the other on the CGLIB proxy that Spring created for the Bean, because there is a @Transactional method in the Bean. I had to use EnableTransactionManagement(mode=ASPECTJ) to disable proxy-based transactions to make the CGLIB proxy disappear, so my aspect does not get woven twice. This seems to suggest that Spring AOP is still active despite aspectj-weaver.jar being attatched.

Like I said, aspects will not be applied twice. The easiest is to just run aspectjweaver as a java agent, then you do not even need any Spring annotations Spring will notice that LTW is active. But make sure not to add @Component to native LTW aspects, because AspectJ works outside the Spring context. Making a native aspect also a Spring component could actually really apply it twice.

As for your other problem with seemingly twice executed aspects, I have an idea what you might be doing wrong. Please ask a new question. Please also first learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Thank you. SO is not a discussion forum. Let your code speak, this is how it works here. I would also appreciate you to mark my correct answer here as accepted.

@kriegaex as you suggested in your answer that by using plugin, I can avoid the need of -javaagent. but how do I do this for test when running tests using mvn test?

@SJ1, your question is quite generic. Please, ask a new question instead of hijacking this one and provide a full, minimal sample project on GitHub. Then, I can take a closer look and answer your question.

@kriegaex, Thanks! Could you please check this question?
